# Batch command script, invalid numeric with leading zero?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm trying to generate a script to run ffmpeg on multiple video card inputs by using a loop in batch. So far I have:

This is working great except for when it tries to do:

`set /a cam=%%c` when `c="08"` or `c="09"`. I get:

> Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
>   hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).

What gives? Here's the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%c in (01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11) do (
  set /a cam=%%c
  if !cam! leq 8 (
    echo foobar_sd%%c
  ) else (
    echo barfoo_hd%%c
  )
  pause
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parkydr provided the correct diagnosis as to why you are getting the error - numbers prefixed with `0` are interpreted as octal.

There is a simple solution - change the right side to `08` and add a non numeric character to both sides of the comparison to force a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison. The values sort properly as strings because they are zero padded to all have the same length. I like to use quotes, but nearly any character will do.

```
if "!cam!" leq "08" ...
```

***EDIT***

The solution above doesn't directly address the failure of `SET /A` when `%%c` is `08` or `09`. My solution above assumes the `/A` option has been removed.

The `cam` variable can be eliminated altogether:

```
if "%%c" leq "08" ...
```

Even better yet, the extra non-numeric character(s) is not needed because IF sees `08` as invalid octal notation and defaults to a string comparison.

```
if %%c leq 08 ...
```

See [Rules for how CMD.EXE parses numbers](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3758) for more info. There is a section dedicated to the IF statement.

Comment: How would then for example a value in cam of 07 be interpreted then? Surely leq requires numeric comparison, so it's going to try and turn "08" into a number again, i.e. octal?

Comment: @deed02392 - No, LEQ does not require numeric values. If either side contains a non-numeric character, then a string based comparison is done instead of a numeric comparison. The 0 padding causes the comparison to give the correct, intended result.

Comment: That's very interesting, I did not think it was logical to have a 'less than' comparison with two strings, since how do you quantify the magnitude of a string in the same way one compares the magnitude of two decimal numbers?

Comment: @deed02392 - Think about how a dictionary lists words in sorted order. If word1 appears before word2, then you can say that word1 is less than word2. The same basic concept is used for comparing strings in every computer language that I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers with leading zeros are interpreted as octal (like 0x indicates hex) so 08 and 09 are bad octal values.