# Why are there no octal literals in C#?

Tags: c#

Why didn't those who develop C# include octal literals beyond hexadecimal and binary literals? What would seem to be the reason for that decision?

Comment: I strongly suspect it's because they're rarely useful, but they *can* be extremely annoying. I've certainly always found it strange that in Java, `int x = 010;` is not the same as `int x = 10;`. I wouldn't mind with an explicit specifier, but just making a leading zero significant is horrible IMO.

Comment: @HansPassant its not about dominance, octal is still a very useful base for triplets. This can also be seen in chmod.

Comment: yeah but octal literals can also be displayed by 0o, wouldn't that be even more logical that just 0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Octal encoding is a relic from computing in the late 1950s and 60s.  Back then it was quite useful, companies built machines with a 6-bit byte, commonly packed in an 18-bit or 36-bit word.  6-bits was enough for everybody, teletypes and printers did not yet have lowercase letters and English was the dominant language.

Octal is nice for such 6-bit bytes, takes 2 digits and all bits are used.

That did peter out, inevitably, the IBM-360 was very influential and it had an 8-bit byte.  The PDP-11 of 1970 was important, an affordable 16-bit machine with an 8-bit byte. Around 1975 the olden architectures acquired dinosaur status and programmers started heavily favoring hex.  Octal is clumsy to encode 8 bit bytes, hex gave us the 2 digits back.  Microprocessor kits of the era all used hex.

Octal did last a lot longer than it should have.  DEC manuals always used octal notation, even for the 8-bitters.  The C language brought it into the curly-brace languages, narrowly, it started life on GE-635 and PDP-8, 6-bit machines.  Narrowly, it didn't become real C until the PDP-11, but the seed was planted.  With a way to specify octal values that was far too easy, a leading 0 on the literal.

Producing countless bugs and extremely confused programmers.  The C# team thoroughly removed such common bug generators from their curly-brace language.  They did a terrific job.

Comment: "Producing countless bugs and extremely confused programmers." - Can anyone verify this? Been doing this for a long time and have encountered neither in the wild.

Comment: Too many to choose from wild SO, but I liked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749882/batch-command-script-invalid-numeric-with-leading-zero).

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people use 0 as prefix for visual alignments, having octal literals is commonly seen as footgun in programming languages.

```
var x =  11;
var y = 011;
```

This can happen by accident while hex and binary literals require a special alphanumeric prefix `0x` or `0b`. Modern languages try to reduce these kinds of footguns.

Comment: yeah but it still could be developed in a 0o way or something like that,
and in your particular example one can use _ instead of 0, can't they?

Comment: Its an uncommon use-case so they probably decided to just not include it at all.